# Using the autolayout visual format language is it possible to set the width of a view equal to the height of the same view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, visual-format-language

Using the autolayout visual format language is it possible to set the width of a view equal to the height of the same view?

Here is what I want to do:

```
[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[stopButton(100)]" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:views]];
[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[stopButton(stopButton.height)" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to create a fixed aspect ratio constraint which, according to the [documentation for the visual formatting language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html), is not possible currently.

> One useful constraint that cannot be expressed is a fixed aspect ratio
>   (for example, imageView.width = 2 * imageView.height). To create such
>   a constraint, you must use
>   constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:.

Answer (score 0):

Luke Van In's answer on a fixed aspect ratio is a great answer!

Of course, if you simply want to use the same value in multiple places you would modify the code to use a metrics dictionary as follows:

```
 NSDictionary* metrics = @{@"stopButtonSize":@100};
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[stopButton(stopButtonSize)]" options:kNilOptions metrics:metrics views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[stopButton(stopButtonSize)]" options:kNilOptions metrics:metrics views:views]];
```